# R How to take the median of the last n # of nonzero terms in dataframe

Tags: r, vector, median

If I have a dataframe like such:

```
df1
vec1  vec2 vec3 
0     1    5    
1     4    3    
2     3    7    
0     0    0    
0     5    0
```

And I want it as such:

```
df1
vec1  vec2 vec3 vec1median vec2median vec3median
0     1    10   2.75       4          9 
1     4    3    2.75       4.25       7
2     3    7    4          5          9
0     0    0    4          5          9   
4     5    9    4          5          9
4     5    9    ..         ..         ..
```

Where `vec(N)median` is the median value of `vec(N)` (applied on a rolling basis travelling upwards) to their respective `N` (1, 2, and 3).

The tricky part is this: I want to be able to take the median while ignoring zeros (as seen in the example). On top of that, I want to specify how far back the median function will be applied. I want to specify whether the "rolling median" will be applied to `df1$vec1[x:x+100]` or any value besides 100. I am okay if this uses a for loop. Separately, I would also like to be able to apply the rolling median to the last n non-zero instances of `vec1`.

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean `mean` instead of `median`?  Looking just at `vec1`, the values there correspond to means, not medians.  It might be useful to reduce the problem the computation on a single vector, and then think about generalizing.

Comment: I gave the 3 vectors as examples in case 1 vector didn't make it clear enough. Its fine if the answer only applies to 1 vector. If you look closely at vec1median, you will see that it is indeed the median of vec1.

Comment: `median(c(1, 2, 4, 4))` is 3, not 2.75 -- for even numbers the median is the mean of the middle two elements, so for integer lists will never have a decimal part not equal to 0 or .5.  I just want to clarify to be sure the question is asking what its body is saying.

Comment: Yes, you are correct the values should be the means of the middle two, not the whole index. My mistake.

Comment: Assuming that this is just a data error, I think the ideal approach would be to replace the `0`s with `NA`s, and then use the `na.rm` parameter in `median` to filter them out -- it sounds like that's effectively how they're being treated, so it might be good from a data cleanliness perspective as well.

Comment: So is the result in the example correct?  And why does the first column turn into `c(0, 1, 2, 0, 4, 4)`?  I don't understand why the original data is changing and getting longer

Comment: this question is unclear for me. Seems like the explanation is really poor for potential helpers. -1

Answer (score 0):

An efficient answer to this problem seems tricky, although I'm sure that there are packages that do that sort of thing.  The easiest (though inefficient) approach that I can think of is based on this:

```
vec1 <- c(1,2,0,0,3,4,1)
sapply(1:length(vec1), function(d) { median (vec1[d:length(vec1)]) })
```

The devil is in the details; specifically, excluding zeroes from the computation, and being able to compute it for a given range of rows.

```
rollup.median <- function(vec, start, end) {
    sapply(start:end, function(roll.start) {
       roll <- vec[roll.start:end]
       median(roll[roll != 0])
    })
}
```

From there, it is just a matter of applying it to each of the columns as desired.

```
> sapply(df1, function(d) { rollup.median(d, 1, 5)})
     vec1 vec2 vec3
[1,]  1.5  3.5    5
[2,]  1.5  4.0    5
[3,]  2.0  4.0    7
[4,]   NA  5.0   NA
[5,]   NA  5.0   NA
```

Comment: The first example seemed to work well for the first goal when I changed the d:length(vec1) to my desired "look back period". Is that correct for accomplishing my first goal?

Comment: Can you describe the effect of the second code (rollup.median)?

Comment: I added an example of the usage of `rollup.median` to the end of the question; hopefully it clarifies.

Answer (score 0):

I think I am understanding the question correctly. Pass the vectors from your data frame and starting index into this function to get a vector of rolling medians.

```
 RollMedNoZeros <- function(x, StartRow) {
     sapply(StartRow:length(x) - 1, function(a) { median(x[-union(which(x == 0), match(x[1:a], x))]) })
 }

 vec <- c(0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 3)
 RollMedNoZeros(vec, 1)
 [1] 2.0 2.0 2.5 2.5 3.0 3.0

 RollMedNoZeros(vec, 2)
 [1] 2.0 2.5 2.5 3.0 3.0

 RollMedNoZeros(vec, 3)
 [1] 2.5 2.5 3.0 3.0

 vec2 <- c(0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 3, 0, 0)
 RollMedNoZeros(vec2, 1)
 [1] 2.0 2.0 2.5 2.5 3.0 3.0  NA  NA
```

Comment: To be clear, this accomplishes the goal of going back N number of rows, not N number of non-zero instances, correct?

Comment: I think adding a [which(a != 0)] in the anonymous function will work but I'm in the car and can't test right now.

Comment: I think you need to define 'a' in the function. Maybe you meant function(a, StartRow)?

Comment: Sorry. Sloppy mistakes. I made some fixes.